# How null object can still return its property value?

Tags: java

Below is my code. I set the object to null, still my print statement can print the property `name` correctly. Can anyone tell me what's happening?

```
public class MyClass {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String s) {
        name = s;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.changeName(obj);

        System.out.println("Name = " + obj.getName());
    }
    public MyClass() {
        name = "A";
    }

    public void changeName(MyClass obj) {
         obj.setName("B");
         obj = null;
    }
}
```

Output is:

> Name = B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj = null` only sets the local variable `obj` of the method `changeName` to `null`. It doesn't affect the object referenced by that variable in any way.

Comment: Or the variable whose value was passed by value as a parameter to the method.

Comment: Then how come obj.SetName sets to the property of the original object instead of local variable?

Comment: @Sunil the local variable `obj` holds a reference to the original object, so `obj.setName("B")` is equivalent to `this.setName("B")`.

Comment: Ok. Got it thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

I apologize if this incorrect, I have been working with Kotlin lately and it’s messing with my head.

I would try either

```
 public void changeName(MyClass obj) {
     obj.setName("B");
     obj.setName(null);
}
```

Or you might try

```
 public void changeName(MyClass obj) {
     obj.setName("B");
     obj.setName().empty;
}
```

I think it has something to do with the fact your passing an object to that method and setting the value of the object and the null must be either nulling the incorrect object or the setName value is still holding its value even though the object itself is null. So you need to set the setName value to null I think.

Comment: You might also try making the method return an object? Then you could receive that object and null it at that point?